# Partially inherit dependencies from configuration

Tags: gradle, dependencies, build.gradle

If I have a few dependencies in configuration preRuntime and want configuration runtime to inherit them all, except a couple, is there a way in gradle to do something like:

```
runtime.extendsFrom('preRuntime'){exclude `com.foo:bar:1.0'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing:

```
dependencies{
    runtime project.configurations.getByName('preRuntime')
        .filter {it.name != 'bar'}
}
```